# Unable to start services in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, vsftpd, oraclelinux

I'm trying to run a ftp service inside a docker container (plan is to deploy it to AKS). However, I'm unable to start the sshd and vsftpd services while running the container. Any help/guidance/pointer please. Here's the dockerfile I'm using.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
RUN yum install -y sudo initscripts
RUN mkdir -p /var/config

COPY sshd_config /var/config/sshd_config
COPY vsftpd_config /var/config/vsftpd_config

RUN echo "sftpusersnokey sftpuserswithkey ftpusers" |xargs -n1 groupadd ${g};
RUN sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
RUN yum -y install blobfuse fuse vsftpd ftp systemd-sysv iptables-services openssh-server perl

RUN cat /var/config/sshd_config >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN sed -i 's/anonymous_enable=YES/anonymous_enable=NO/; s/listen_ipv6=YES/listen_ipv6=NO/; s/listen=NO/listen=YES/; s/xferlog_std_format=YES/xferlog_std_format=NO/; s/#chroot_local_user=YES/chroot_local_user=YES/;' /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

RUN sed  -i -r 's/auth(\s+)required(\s+)pam_shells.so/#auth\1required\2pam_shells.so/;' /etc/pam.d/vsftpd

RUN sed -i -r 's!^Subsystem(\s+)sftp(\s+)/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server!#Subsystem\1sftp\2/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server\nSubsystem\1sftp\2internal-sftp!;' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN cat /var/config/vsftpd_config >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

EXPOSE 20 21 10090-10100

ENTRYPOINT service iptables stop && service sshd restart && service vsftpd restart && /bin/bash
```

Comment: This setup sounds like you want a virtual machine, with multiple users, interactive logins, and a service manager.  A Docker container typically runs _one_ process and doesn't configure interactive-login parts like PAM or an ssh daemon.  You don't generally "start services in a container": a container runs a single service as a foreground process.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, yes, the initial solution is based on linux VMs only. We wanted to containerize it to avoid manual deployment. Idea is - whenever there's a new user, we will update and redeploy all the docker containers. Do you think this will be at all possible with docker?

Comment: You might look at tools like Packer that can produce VM images from a text-file description; you could probably implement this workflow on your existing VM system.

Comment: If I start the container without (re)starting the services, take a terminal into the container and then try to run the services manually then it works. Only problem I'm facing is - I'm unable to (re)start/stop the services when I'm running the container without manual intervention.

Comment: A Docker container doesn't typically run any sort of init system that `service` could communicate with.  This isn't a typical design for a container: you would typically run the two services in separate containers, as the only process in their respective containers, without running `service` or `bash`.